# Spreading hourly data to 5 minutes in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to transfer and spread a lot of data and copy/paste them for every 5 minutes within each hour,as illustrated in the image enclosed.
What is the way to do it automatically, without having to copy and paste every single line?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQOkk.png)

I have copied and pasted but it takes ages

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.
Paste all your data 12 times below each other. (Now you have the same data 12 times).

Step 2.
Then sort by date.
Now you have the same day 12 times in a row.

Step 3.
Add a time colum.

Step 4.
Add one hour with 5 minute intervals in the time column, select this hour and copy it down.

This should solve your problem.